# Setting CSS style attributes with thymeleaf

Tags: css, thymeleaf

How to set the background property of a style tag with a thymeleaf resolved url.

I have

```
<div style="background:url('<url-to-image>')"></div>
```

Is there a `<img th:src="${@/<path-to-image>}">` equivalent for setting style attributes in thymeleaf.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could achieve that if you use `th:style` to set your style attribute:

```
<div th:style="'background:url(' + @{/<path-to-image>} + ');'"></div>
```

Check [this](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/URLs-in-style-attributes-td4027989.html) thread on thymeleaf forum.

Comment: Thanks. The syntax can be a real headache at times.

Comment: how can i pass variable from backend to  width property

Comment: I am getting following exception in spring boot: cannot be context relative (/) or page relative unless you implement the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (context is of class: org.thymeleaf.context.Context)

Answer (score 9):

The answer suggested by @Leandro Carracedo did not work for me (but it helped along the way), I had to add second pair of brackets and '$' to get the value out of the variable

```
<td th:style="'font-size:'+@{${headerTemplateTextSize}}+'; -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em; -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em; -webkit-margin-start: 0px;-webkit-margin-end: 0px; font-weight: 300; max-width: 100px'">
    <div>...</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use literal substitutions:

```
<div th:style="|background:url(@{/<path-to-image>});|"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope it will help someone.

Please make sure that your image SIZE is SMALLER than screen size in pixels. Otherwise, neither 'background' nor 'background-image' did not work for me.

Leandro's syntax works fine. Consider using this one as well ( 'background-image' instead of 'background' )

```
<div th:style="'background-image:url(' + @{/images/R1.jpg} + ');'">
```

This one stretches out the image instead of repeating it if image is smaller ( no need to state 'no-repeat' )

Comment: Completely irrelevant. Please stick to the topic and use a comment instead.

Comment: @Jelle Blaauw  - you are cool man. I still hope / believe it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks bro, me ayudo bastante!!