# parameter css width in thymeaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Mi code is:

```
<tr th:each="planificacion : ${planificaciones}"
                        th:onclick="'window.location.href = \'' + @{/planificacion/{idp}(idp=${planificacion.id})}+ '\''">

                        <td th:text="${planificacion.nombre}"></td>
                        <td>
                            <div th:if="${planificacion.completado}">
                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success"
                                    style="font-size: 80%; padding: 6px 18px;">Completo</span>
                            </div>
                            <div th:if="${not planificacion.completado}">
                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger"
                                    style="font-size: 80%; padding: 6px 18px;">Incompleto</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            **<div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active"
                                    role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0"
                                    aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
                                    <span id="current-progress"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>**
                        </td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-danger"
                            th:href="@{/borrar_planificacion/{id}(id=${planificacion.id})}">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                        </a></td>


                    </tr>
                </table>
```

I want to change width value with controller variable ${planificacion.porcentaje}, but I don´t know.

How I can do it?

I read this post but it doesn´t work for me. [Setting CSS style attributes with thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140647/9974583)

Comment: Can you show how you are using `${planificacion.porcentaje}`?

Comment: Style width is de progress of the progress bar, and porcentaje is an variable to database planificacion. Then I want use this variable porcentaje to show progress in progress bar

Answer (score 2):

As per the  [Thymeleaf documentation - Setting attribute values](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes)

Use `th:width="${planificacion.porcentaje}"` or `th:attr="width=${planificacion.porcentaje}"`