# How to add static image in inline background-image css tag in Spring boot Thymleaf template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am developing a web application for learning purpose using `java spring` and `Thyme leaf` template engine.

In one of my `Thymeleaf` page, I want to add an image as a *background-image* using inline `CSS`. My image is in the static folder,
I have tried to use various method found on the internet but none of them worked. 
I've searched and unfortunately failed to find out the solution to this problem.

I've tried to `th:style tag` and searched in google to find out how this tag works but unfortunately couldn't able to understand this tag properly.

I've added the code and the screenshot of the error.

[image]

```
blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/TOr6Nyn"><a > 
href="//imgur.com/TOr6Nyn"></a></blockquote><script async   
src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

th:style="'background-image: url('+ 
@{~/frontend/images/blog/default/thum1.jpg}+')'"
```

Comment: Can you describe what is the error that you are facing other than just a red mark shown on your IDE.
Your code supposed to be working and I paste it in my IDE but not showing any error highlighting and it is working too.

Comment: Your usage seems ok. Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140647/setting-css-style-attributes-with-thymeleaf. It is exactly the same as what you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `style` attribute to your div as:

```
style="background-image: url(<c:url value="/resources/images/bg_1.jpg"/>)"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have also tried static image but it does not work.
But if u want to show image on page use base64 of that image.

Use this code on your thyme leaf page:

```
<img th:src="@{data:image/png;base64,YOUR BASE 64}
```